# Looking for information about the number of Fulbright scholarships per country

Tags: data-request

I am looking for data about the total number of Fulbright scholarships that have been granted to international students to come to the US since the program's inception, as well as the scholarhip's total used funds.

Comment: [Some statistics](https://us.fulbrightonline.org/statistics).